# Py2exe'd Python script cant save image in TIFF format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, py2exe, tiff

There is a python script i'm working on which processes an Image and converts and saves it from a GIF image into a TIFF format with extension ".tif"...

The script works fine and even gives me the proper output..

However, when i convert it into an exe using Py2exe(even tried Cx-Freeze)
it is unable to save the processed image in TIFF format... it throws the following error:

> File "PIL\Image.pyc", line 1423, in save KeyError: '.tif'

the code for saving the image looks like this..

```
im_orig = Image.open(path1)
big = im_orig.resize((116, 56), Image.NEAREST)
ext = ".tif"
new=path.replace('.','') 
newpath=new+"input-NEAREST"+ext
newimage=big.save(newpath)
```

I even tried changing the above code as follows to avoid the Key Error

```
im_orig = Image.open(path1)
big = im_orig.resize((116, 56), Image.NEAREST)
new=path.replace('.','') 
newpath=new+"input-NEAREST.tif"
newimage=big.save(newpath, "TIFF" )
```

The changed code once again works perfectly fine when i run it as a script ,

but throws error when i run the script as an executable !

The error i get is:

```
\PIL\Image.py", line 1429, in save
save_handler = SAVE[string.upper(format)] # unknown format
KeyError: 'TIFF'
```

apparently the error is supposed to be in this line:

```
newimage=big.save(newpath, "TIFF" )
```

Will really appreciate any help or guidance in solving this problem.

Comment: Please use code formatting the next time instead of quote formatting. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to the delayed initialization of image plugins in PIL. Once it is compiled, it is unable to find these plugins. The solution is to manually import the required plugin. So what you will need is

```
import TiffImagePlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, except when using cx_freeze instead of py2exe.  Raja Selvaraj's solution fixed it for me.